# Does it affect the burn down chart?

Tags: agile

We finished the development and closed the sprint(two weeks). But the code has not been reviewed. So in the third week we don't start a new sprint and keep clean up(refactor) the code. The scrum master told us that we can still log the time to the previous tasks.

My question is that since we close the sprint, does it effect the sprint's burn down chart?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your definition of done ([1](https://www.scrumalliance.org/community/articles/2008/september/what-is-definition-of-done-(dod)), [2](http://guide.agilealliance.org/guide/definition-of-done.html), [3](http://www.allaboutagile.com/definition-of-done-10-point-checklist/)) requires that you review your implementation to complete a story, then you cannot take credit for completing the story and the burn down chart does not reflect a completed story. Keep in mind that a story is either completed or not, and the burn down chart doesn't reflect credit for completing the work until the definition of done is met and the story is complete.

I would suggest looking at your process, though. If you started so many stories that you couldn't adequately close them, it sounds like you're taking on too much work. Are you estimating your whole definition of done? Are you adjusting your capacity for the Sprint based on your team's velocity? Are your Sprints too short (should you plan for 3-week Sprints instead of two)?

Comment: The problem is that we don't have code review process but we have to refactor the code as clean code requirements. Which means we don't have a place to log my work.

Comment: @Love Everything that you need to do to meet your definition of done needs to be estimated. It sounds like you are either underestimating your stories and not including all of the effort or bringing in too many story points into the sprint.

Comment: Does burn down chart burns points when team completes the work or when PO accepts the story ? If PO has not accept the story , do we burn the points or not?

Comment: @Hitesh What is considered "done" by the team's process? Work is either "done" or "not done", and the burn down happens once work is "done". If acceptance by the PO is required for work to be "done", then that's when burn down happens.

Answer (score 3):

Have you closed the sprint or not? Extending it to a 3rd week sounds like you're still working it, unless you have a week's sprint for code review. Either way... who cares. If all your sprints measure code creation (and all review is done afterwards) then yes, close your burndown chart and start a new one when you start your next sprint.

The point of the burndown is to measure how much you actually get done compared to how much you thought you'd get done. That's all. Its solely a tool to help you plan your next sprint.

Answer (score 2):

At the end of the day, if you're still working on a previous sprint in to week 3, it's still active. Most sprints are designed with refactoring and code review requirements already in mind. If you're coming to find that your refactoring/code review is bleeding over in to another week, I'd suggest adjusting your team's point forecasting to save time for those (pretty important) processes.

To answer your question more bluntly: no, I don't think it affects the burndown because of your current situation, but it ought to. Adjust/iterate on your proceses to save your team enough time to handle all sprint requirements during its alloted time.